# Voice repeating software for Windows PC/Android

Tags: windows, android, audio, voice-recording

I am trying to work on my accent these days. One of the thing I feel can help me is speak and then listen to my voice.

I am looking for something like "Talking tom" mobile app. Something who listen what I say, and when I stop, repeat as it is. Any suggestions? Looking for software preferably for Windows PC, otherwise android.

Comment: Did you tried this [Repeat voice recorder](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kimhyunjin.MyRealVoice&hl=en)

Comment: @Abhishekgurjar Thanks! I will try it now